# Expected class name before "{" token HERENCIA c++

Tags: c++, poo, herencia

Estoy realizando un programa con una clase padre llamada empleado y otra clase hija llamada repartidor. Estoy intentando que repartidor herede de empleado sus atributos pero me da error y no se cual es. El error esta marcado con un comentario en *repartidor.h*. Avisenme si es necesario publicar el .cpp (no me ha dado error en ninguna funcion). Adjunto el codigo (sin el .cpp):

empleado.h

```
#ifndef EJ2_HERENCIA_PPARCIAL
#define EJ2_HERENCIA_PPARCIAL

using namespace std;
#include <iostream>

class Empleado {
protected:
    std::string nombre;
    int edad;
    int salario;

public:

Empleado () = default;
Empleado (string, int, int);

void setNombre (std::string);
void setEdad (int);
void setSalario (int);

std::string getNombre ();
int getEdad ();
int getSalario ();

void mostrarEmpleado ();

};

#endif // EJ2_HERENCIA_PPARCIAL
```

repartidor.h

```
#ifndef EJ2_HERENCIA_PPARCIAL
#define EJ2_HERENCIA_PPARCIAL

using namespace std;
#include <iostream>
#include "empleado.h"

class Repartidor :public Empleado {  //ACA ME DA EL ERROR!
protected:
    int zona;
public:
    Repartidor () = default;
    Repartidor (string, int, int, int);
    void setZona (int);
    int getZona ();

    void mostrarEmpleado();

    void plusRepartidor ();
};

#endif // EJ2_HERENCIA_PPARCIAL
```

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster Efestivamente, he tenido que repasar para verlo... no se lo cuentes a Trauma D:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cuando intentas heredar de `Empleado` esa clase no existe, por eso el compilador se queja diciendo que esperaba un nombre de clase antes de `{`.

La clase `Empleado` no existe porque has repetido los [include guards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard):

###### `empleado.h`

```
#ifndef EJ2_HERENCIA_PPARCIAL
#define EJ2_HERENCIA_PPARCIAL

...

#endif // EJ2_HERENCIA_PPARCIAL
```

###### `repartidor.h`

```
#ifndef EJ2_HERENCIA_PPARCIAL
#define EJ2_HERENCIA_PPARCIAL

...

#endif // EJ2_HERENCIA_PPARCIAL
```

Esto sucede porque al hacer en `repartidor.h` la inclusión de `empleado.h` la primera línea de este archivo pregunta si **NO** está definido `EJ2_HERENCIA_PPARCIAL` que resulta **SÍ** estar definido unas líneas antes, por lo que nada de ese archivo se incluye y en consecuencia la clase `Empleado` no existe.

Te aconsejo que hagas que los *include guard* dependan del nombre del archivo y para evitar repeticiones, además añadiría un espacio de nombres a tus clases que incluiría en el nombre del *include guard*:

###### `empleado.h`

```
#ifndef MIEMPRESA_EMPLEADO_H
#define MIEMPRESA_EMPLEADO_H

namespace MiEmpresa
{

...

}

#endif // MIEMPRESA_EMPLEADO_H
```

###### `repartidor.h`

```
#ifndef MIEMPRESA_REPARTIDOR_H
#define MIEMPRESA_REPARTIDOR_H

namespace MiEmpresa
{

...

}

#endif // MIEMPRESA_REPARTIDOR_H
```

Comment: Una buena alternativa es usar `#pragma once`. Así no tienes que preocuparte de que no se repitan.

Comment: @Mateo me explicarías mejor como es lo del #pragma once ?? De que me serviría y como funciona??

Comment: Gracias me super sirvio! Me estaba volviendo loco ya :c

Comment: @igna1225 escribes `#pragma once` al comienzo del archivo y listo. El compilador no lo incluirá más de una vez. A día de hoy funciona con la mayoría de compiladores. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/impl

Comment: @Mateo `#pragma once` no es estándar así que podría no funcionar en todos los compiladores. Los *include guard* funcionan en cualquier compilador.